# How can I configure Ola Hallengren IndexOptimize script to run against a subset of tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ola-hallengren

I'm using Ola Hallengren IndexOptimize script against a SQL 2016 database that is 7 TB in size, with over 300,000 tables.  I only have a 6 hour window each night to manage indexes.    I'm using the timelimit parameter to stop the job after 6 hours.

The problem is, every night the index job starts at the beginning of the indexes alphabetically, and only gets through about the same 4,000 tables.

What can I do to get the index job to cover all the indexes in the database?   Perhaps by creating multiple jobs, one for each night of the week that do a subset of indexes?   Or is there a way to have the job start back up the next day where it previously left off?

All the tables are in the same database schema.  This is a vendor-supplied database, I'm unable to make changes to the database schema.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

My current job  steps are as follows:

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[IndexOptimize]
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@FragmentationLow = NULL, 
@FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE', 
@FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE', 
@FragmentationLevel1 = 10, 
@FragmentationLevel2 = 40,
@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL', 
@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y', 
@PartitionLevel = 'N', 
@MaxDOP = 0,
@SortInTempdb = 'Y',
@TimeLimit = 21600,
@LogToTable = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 9):

Don't defrag your indexes every night. You don't need to anymore on modern hardware (especially with solid-state storage with zero seek times). For daily maintenance, you only need to update modified statistics, and even then you only need to do this when you notice performance degradation (i.e. check what your monitoring system tells you).

Per Ola's site, you can do something like this:

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@FragmentationLow = NULL,
@FragmentationMedium = NULL,
@FragmentationHigh = NULL,
@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'
```

The other thing you can do, for when you do need to defragment indexes (if for example you have deleted a large amount of data), is using SQL Server's [Service Broker](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/03/sql-performance/intro-to-service-broker) to set up the maintenance plan for multiple tables in a batch.

That article is in-depth and difficult to summarise in this reply, but it comes down to creating an asynchronous queue, that fires Agent jobs in parallel.

Answer (score 4):

What [philcart](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues/32#issuecomment-442215135) did should help you 'start back up the next day where it previously left off':

> I run the IndexOptimise in two SQL Agent jobs.
>
> In the first job that runs weekly, I pull out all the indexes that
>   need optimisation using the following,
>
> ```
> @FragmentationLow = NULL,  @FragmentationMedium =
> 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE', 
> @FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE', 
> @FragmentationLevel1 = 5,  @FragmentationLevel2 = 30,  @LogToTable =
> 'Y',  @Execute = 'N';
> ```
>
> This captures the Index rebuild/defrag commands in the CommandLog
>   table. After running the IndexOptimise command, the "EndTime" column
>   is set to null for all the records just inserted.
>
> Then on a daily basis, within our maintenance window, the second job
>   just uses a simple cursor to pull out each command that has an EndTime
>   of NULL and run it if the time window hasn't elapsed.
>
> ```
> DECLARE @sqlCmd nvarchar(max);  DECLARE @maxDuration int = 60; 
> DECLARE @startTime datetime = GETDATE();  DECLARE @totalCmds int =
> (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [dbo].[CommandLog] WHERE [EndTime] IS NULL); 
> DECLARE @currCount int = 0;  DECLARE @cmdSample nvarchar(100);  IF
> @totalCmds > 0  BEGIN -- we have work to do  DECLARE cmds CURSOR
> FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT [ID],[Command] FROM [dbo].[CommandLog] WHERE
> [EndTime] IS NULL ORDER BY [ID] DESC  OPEN cmds  FETCH NEXT FROM cmds
> INTO @logID, @sqlCmd  WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND
> (DATEDIFF(MI,@startTime,GETDATE()) < @maxDuration))  BEGIN  SET
> @currCount += 1;  SET @cmdSample = LEFT(@sqlCmd,60)+'...';  UPDATE
> [dbo].[CommandLog] SET [StartTime] = GETDATE() WHERE [ID] = @logID;
> RAISERROR('Excuting IndexOptimize command for ID:%i (%i of %i) -
> %s',10,1,@logID, @currCount, @totalCmds,@cmdSample) WITH NOWAIT;  EXEC
> sp_executeSql @command = @sqlCmd;  UPDATE [dbo].[CommandLog] SET
> [EndTime] = GETDATE() WHERE [ID] = @logID;  RAISERROR('Command
> complete for ID:%i (%i of %i) - %s',10,1,@logID, @currCount,
> @totalCmds,@cmdSample) WITH NOWAIT;  FETCH NEXT FROM cmds INTO @logID,
> @sqlCmd  END  IF (@currCount < @totalCmds)  BEGIN 
> RAISERROR('IndexOptimize finishing due to elapsed time, executed %i
> commands out of %i',10,1,@currCount, @totalCmds) WITH NOWAIT;  END 
> ELSE  BEGIN  RAISERROR('All commands executed within allowed time
> window',10,1) WITH NOWAIT;  END  CLOSE cmds  DEALLOCATE cmds  END --
> we have work to do  ELSE  BEGIN -- we have work to do 
> RAISERROR('IndexOptimize has nothing to execute',10,1) WITH NOWAIT; 
> END -- we have work to do
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The @Indexes parameter allows you to specify individual indexes or tables. We use it on some very large tables and then exclude that from the main index job for that database.

Read more here: https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html, particularly the **Indexes** section.

You can also create a meta table to populate the list of tables, and schedule and then try running that through a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

If your databases are not set up on SSD, it's important to defrag indexes for better performance.

Defragmentation can also free a lot of disk space. It is not required to perform everyday, but a clean up from time to time is worth to consider.

I've provided a detailed solution on how to resolve the timeout issue of IndexOptimize and how to defrag indexes on big warehouses here : https://medium.com/p/13e0390cf629

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/192484)

Answer (score -1):

You can also look into alternative like **Minion Re-index** at https://www.minionware.net/products-1/reindex/

where it has some different features like DB or Table ordering
https://minionware.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/43000040362-minion-reindex-1-2-how-to-reindex-tables-in-a-specific-order

http://www.midnightsql.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/MinionReindexVsIndexOptimize.pdf